# Implicit Function Theorem exercise

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

I did an exercise in the book *Vector Calculus*[Marsden & Tromba] and I check my answer in the book *Vector Calculus Study Guide and Solutions Manual*[Karen Pao, Frederick Soon] but my answer is not the same and I don't understand why.

> 12. Is it possible to solve the system of equations
>       \begin{align}
>     xy^2+xzu+yv^2 & = 3 \\
>     u^3yz+2xv-u^2v^2 &= 2
>     \end{align}
>       for $u(x,y,z)$, $v(x,y,z)$ near $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)$, $(u,v)=(1,1)$? Compute $\partial u/\partial y$ at $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)$.

This is my answer:
\begin{align}
f_1(x,y,z,u,v) &= xy^2+xzu+yv^2-3 \\
f_2(x,y,z,u,v) &= u^3yz+2xv-u^2v^2-2
\end{align}
$$\Delta =
 \frac{\partial(f_1,f_2)}{\partial (u,v)} =
 \begin{vmatrix} xz & 2vy \\ -2uv^2+3u^2yz & -2u^2v+2x\end{vmatrix}$$
$$\left.\Delta\right|_{(x,y,z,u,v)=(1,1,1,1,1)} = \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 0\end{vmatrix} = -2 \neq 0$$
Thus, it is possible to solve in terms of $x$, $y$, $z$ at the given point.

To compute $\partial v/\partial y$ I derive implicitly:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y} =
 2xy+xz\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+v^2+2yv\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} &= 0 \\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y} = 3u^2yz\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+u^3z+2x\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}-2uv^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}-2u^2v\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} &= 0
\end{align}
$$
For $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)$ we have:
$$
\begin{align}
2+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + v^2+2v\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} &= 0 \\
3u^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+u^3+2\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}-2uv^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}-2u^2v\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} &= 0
\end{align} \tag{1}\label{1}
$$

And, after a boring time, I get:
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = \frac{6u^2+3u^2v^2-u^3-4uv^2-2uv^4}{2+4uv^3-2u^2v-6u^2v}$$

But in the *Solutions Manual*, they substitute also $(u,v)=(1,1)$ in $\eqref{1}$(which is much faster) and their answer is
$$
\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = -1
$$

If that's correct, I don't understand it because in the exercise they ask us to compute $\partial v/\partial y$ at $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)$

Comment: "In the exercise they ask us to compute $\partial v/\partial y$ at $(x,y,z)=(1,1)$". That's not what's asked at the top. In any (I didn't check all of your work) the given answer seems to have a typo, because if it was $u$ instead of $v$, it would be correct.

Comment: Thanks, @GitGud, it was a typo.